# Is it safe/acceptable to have duplicate CFC names?

Tags: oop, coldfusion

I've got a bunch of CFCs that I'm trying to organise into folders so it's easier to know what CFC does what, rather than relying on just the file name.

So now the folder that a CFC is in makes it understandable as to what it does. For example:

```
mysite/cfc/security/user.cfc
mysite/cfc/security/page.cfc
mysite/cfc/users/page.cfc
```

So here we have a duplicate name of `page.cfc` which are two different CFCs doing different things. One interacts with the user's page, the other interacts with the security page. This is just an example, of course.

The other alternative I can think of is to have all CFCs in a folder and prefix them with what application area they affect, e.g.:

```
mysite/cfc/security-user.cfc
mysite/cfc/security-page.cfc
mysite/cfc/user-page.cfc
```

These are poor names but hopefully you get the gist of it.

What's the best way to go about this? Class names (therefore CFCs) should be nouns and both ways of doing it adheres to that. But which one is better practice or is there an entirely better way of doing this?

Comment: Having classes/CFCs with the same name is common practice. It is the 'path' or 'package' that should be unique.

Comment: @ScottStroz I thought that CFCs = classes which model objects. So lets take cars as an example. Wouldn't it be better to have `mysite/cars/volvo.cfc, mysite/cars/bmw.cfc` rather than `mysite/volvo/car.cfc, mysite/bmw/car.cfc`. I'm just curious.

Comment: 'Better' - depends on your point of view, really. I would go with the former. But, based on your initial question, you have 2 CFCs with the same name, but different paths (packages). Also acceptable and done frequently.

Comment: Bear in mind that after you move a cfc you might have to re-start ColdFusion.  It will have the old location cached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say put files in related folders. It will make it easier to find the files based on its function.

When you use them you can specify the path to them. `createObject("component", "cfc.securit.user")`

Comment: I've put lots of duplicate names in different folders based on what they do.  dao/user.cfc  gateway/user.cfc for example.  You can always distinguish the names when you create them.  For example:  objUserDao=createObject("component", "cfc.dao.user");

Answer (score 2):

The path to a CFC includes its directory name, `mysite/cfc/security/page.cfc` and `mysite/cfc/users/page.cfc` are not considered the same. So it doesn't matter you have two files called `page.cfc`.

Of course if you don't path your CFC references then there's ambiguity, but you should always either fully path them or import the package dir before referencing them anyhow.

Comment: It doesn't affect the web application, but it is acceptable OOP practice to have duplicate class names? When classes are meant to be a representation of an object?

Comment: It's fine. It's why packages exist in the first place. Your requirement for what it is to be an Animal might be completely different from my requirement, so you'd have com.volumeone.zoo.Animal, and I might have com.adam.farm.Animal. That said, your examples above might be leading you astray. It's more likely to be mysite/cfc/pages/Security.cfc and mysite/cfc/pages/User.cfc I think. Of course it depends on what you're modelling though, and for what purpose.